# random number generator in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, prng, fortran-common-block

I am testing the RNG code as mentioned in link (fortran 77 code):
https://www.cisl.ucar.edu/zine/96/spring/articles/3.random-6.html
which applies the Park & Miller algorithm.

the function call of the program is

```
call srand(seed)  
x=rand()
```

However the program does not seem to respond to the seeding by srand(), i.e., the x-value is unaffected by the initial seeding, and always equal to ~0.218. I suspect that this has to do with the definition of the common block and data block, as the value of x is equivalent to putting the seed as 123456789, which is the initialization value defined in the datablock.

Any ideas?

I am compiling with gfortran.

Comment: How do you define `seed`?

Comment: @Cheery: integer(8) seed. seed = ...

Comment: No, what it is equal to? Do not tell me that you are not changing it )) Same seed will give same results.

Comment: Yes I am changing it each time I compile the program. 142, 1522 etc. etc.. and they give the same result of x.

Comment: Trying, but not in gfortran.. seed = 1 gives `7.8263693E-06`, seed = 2 gives `1.5652739E-05` and so on.. Let me check with gfortran.

Comment: No problem, the same results in gfortran. `7.62939453E-06` for seed = 1 and `1.54972076E-05` for seed = 2. `GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2` Check that your seed is actually changing.

Comment: @Cheery: Hmm that's rather weird... Are you sure you are using the random number generator specified by the program or the rng by fortran (by default fortran has the rng of same name). I double checked my code, by putting the function rand() inside a module vs outside a module, the former ignores the srand() call. Or say, rename the function from rand() to rand1()

Comment: I was using the code provided by the link, nothing else. Let me rename it to check.

Comment: @francescalus: Noted. I actually did not define the variable seed, only putting in srand(134) or srand(1444) etc.

Comment: @Rain I tried both ways, also I renamed rand to rand2. It works under Intel's fortran, but under gfortran - yes, the same number all the time. And yes, JSEED does not change. The problem is that original srand is called - rename it.

Comment: Not a good idea to generate random numbers in functins instead of subroutines.

Comment: @VladimirF: could you explain why?

Comment: read https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/oZ-pMnfteWI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that the original `srand` and `rand` may be called. I renamed functions to `srand2` and `rand2` and everything start to work as expected.

For `seed = 1` the result is `7.82636926E-06` and for `seed = 2` the result is `1.56527385E-05`. Checked it in gfortran and in Intel's fortran.

Comment: Thanks! that's really something weird, ifort vs gfortran wise. Anyway it worked.